# Многоразовый печатающийся текст. Как в VN

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Читали визуальные новеллы?
Текст появляется по одной букве и происходить это должно неограниченное кол-во раз. Например

```
 var txt ="Выпад был сродни вспышке молнии";
 function()//которая берёт этот вар и записывает в `div` подобающем образом
```

Условия:

Текст меняется с помощью `innerHTML`

Можно записать в 1-2 строки

И вопрос

У браузера не возникет проблем с 40мб локальных скриптов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть библиотека `typed.js`.

```js
var options = {
  strings: ["Первое предложение", "Второе предложение", "И так далее"],
  typeSpeed: 100
}

var typed = new Typed(".element", options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.5/typed.min.js"></script>
<div class="element"></div>
```